# System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry point named 'AsaConnection_CloseDataRead

Tags: ado.net, sqlanywhere

My application uses the SQL Anywhere ADO .NET data provider. I had upgraded my application to use SQL Anywhere 12.0.1 EBF 3840 earlier in the week, but I had to roll it back to EBF 3817 on Friday. I've been getting the following error when my program starts up:

```
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry point named 'AsaConnection_CloseDataReaders' in DLL 'dbdata12.dll'.
```

I've done a search and I found [this documentation page](http://dcx.sybase.com/1201/en/dbprogramming/adodotnet-dev-dbdata.html) about dbdata12.dll. I've done a search of the C: drive on my machine and I can't find dbdata12.dll anywhere on it. Apparently, the program isn't unpacking it, either.

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of another developer here, I’ve resolved this.

The problem is that the uninstaller does not remove all 3840 DLLs from the GAC.  Specifically, I found copies of iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.V4.0.dll and policy.12.0.iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.V4.0.dll and policy.12.0.iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.V4.5.dll in the C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL folders for EBF 3840, even after I had uninstalled SQL Anywhere from my machine twice.

Once I deleted those DLLs, the problem stopped.